# How can you get your character to stop speaking?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've started a new character in Guild Wars 2.  Occasionally, at seemingly random times, it will say something like "A little help here" or "Never waste a corpse".  Just speaking out loud to itself, it seems.

Is there a way to get the character to stop speaking?

Comment: The characters randomly speaking random stuff in random voices is a known bug that was introduced in the recent (16.03.) update. The devs are aware of the bug, I suspect it will be fixed soon. Cf. https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/support/bugs/Hearing-Player-Shouts-for-Map

Comment: According to the patch notes, this bug was fixed today. https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/updates/Game-Update-Notes-March-16-2015/first#post4899333 @Brian

Comment: Just want to say I'm oddly weirded out by referring to a character as "it".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a bug in the latest patch. Your character's lips will move, and it will sound like it is coming from your character, but it is actually caused by other characters on the map.

These bits of dialogue are normally triggered by your character gaining a boon, gaining a condition, becoming downed, being revived, using a shout, gaining a level, uncovering a new part of the map, or other changes to your character's state.

This is a known issue, and will likely be fixed soon. In the meantime, you can go to [Options (F11) -> Audio (third tab) -> Dialog Volume](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Options#Sound_Options), and move that slider all the way to the left. Note that this will mute all speech, not just that of your own character.